# How to reset the products grid filter don't loading in the admin panel?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, filter

My backend keeps freezing and can't do anything with it. I think it is due to the filter that was put last week on the products page to show 1000 products in the grid.

[image: Magento 2 reset the products grid filter]

I tried to open it in an incognito window but it didn't work.

How could I fix it with no access to this page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove it from the database. I will provide examples using Magerun2.

#### 1 - Admin user

Access your database and list the admin users, and find your admin user ID there.

```
magerun admin:user:list
```

#### 2 - Find the data

Run this command below to enter into the DB.

```
magerun db:console
```

Then get the list of UI Bookmarks that you have saved in the DB using this command.

```
SELECT 'namespace' FROM ui_bookmark;
```

#### 3 - Remove it

Then remove the data saved to the product grid according to your admin user ID, my admin user ID is 3 so I ran these commands below.

```
DELETE FROM ui_bookmark WHERE user_id='3' AND namespace='product_listing';
DELETE FROM ui_bookmark WHERE user_id='3' AND namespace='product_attributes_grid';
```